# How can I fix the error eval:2:0: provide: not at module level

Tags: jupyter-notebook, racket

```
(provide my-class-getter my-class-setter)

eval:2:0: provide: not at module level
  in: (provide my-class-getter my-class-setter)
  location...:
   eval:2:0
  context...:
   raise-syntax-error
   apply-transformer-in-context
   apply-transformer52
   dispatch-transformer41
   expand-capturing-lifts
   loop
   /Applications/Racket v7.0/share/pkgs/sandbox-lib/racket/sandbox.rkt:493:0: call-with-custodian-shutdown
   /Applications/Racket v7.0/collects/racket/private/more-scheme.rkt:148:2: call-with-break-parameterization
   .../more-scheme.rkt:261:28
   /Applications/Racket v7.0/share/pkgs/sandbox-lib/racket/sandbox.rkt:861:5: loop
```

I just set up iracket in jupyter notebook. Seems it doesn't support `provide`.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Can you give a little more context. You have a program in an jupyter notebook? Are those (implicit) modules or do they works as a repl? (provide belongs inside a module, and can't be used in the repl)

Comment: It is some tasks from my lab. I want to do it using iracket (jupyter notebook). https://mcs.utm.utoronto.ca/~324/exc/exc4/starter-code/ex4.rkt

Comment: The program in ex4.rkt works as-is in DrRacket, so it must be an iracket issue. I recommend contacting the author of iracket.

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Dont give more infos in comments, put all relevant information into comments please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cells of an IRacket notebook are like individual interactions at the REPL. So you cannot use the `provide` form, which is only allowed at the top level of a module.